# How to use LSI SAS3041E RAID card?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, hardware-raid

I have a LSI SAS3041E RAID card which I am attempting to use with an Asrock Fatality Gaming K6. When I turn the computer on, I am not given any option to enter the card's BIOS area and nor does pressing ctrl-c have any notable effect. However when I boot into the OS, the hard drives attached to the card are visible.

I am using Fedora Core 26. If there is any easy to use RAID software with Fedora, that would be good too.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you need to select "Launch Storage OpROM Policy" to "Legacy Only" in the Advanced area of the UEFI setup utility under the "Boot" tab.